# DeleteAfterInstall flag not deleting files once installation is complete

Tags: inno-setup

I've got some additional files to install some runtime engines that are required for my application (Access database engine and Crystal Reports runtimes).

I'm setting them to use the `deleteafterinstall` flag, so once they've been installed and the application install is complete, it should delete the files, however, I've tested it on my work PC and my personal laptop and despite the application and runtimes being installed without any issues, the runtimes installers aren't being deleted.

```
[Files]
Source: "\\my_Directory\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: RunAccessInstaller; Flags: deleteafterinstall;

[Code]
procedure RunAccessInstaller;
var
   ResultCode: Integer;
begin
   if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
               ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
then
   MsgBox('Microsoft Office Engine installer failed to run!' + #13#10 +
          SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

After removing `AfterInstall: RunAccessInstaller` along with the `RunAccessInstaller` procedure itself, this still doesn't delete the file.

The script now appears as below, so it seems as though the `deleteafterinstall` flag isn't working.

```
[Files]
Source: "\\server\common\David\Iconysis Agent Installer Files\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe"; _
         DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall;
```

The full log file when running a fresh install onto my Desktop (installation run without installing `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`)

> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.236   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+00:00)
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.236   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.9 (a)
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.236   Original Setup EXE: \server\common\David\IAInstaller\IAInstaller.exe
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.237   Setup command line: /SL5="$1B0596,77447651,97792,\server\common\David\IAInstaller\IAInstaller.exe" /SPAWNWND=$2F0524 /NOTIFYWND=$D0576
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.237   Windows version: 10.0.15063  (NT platform: Yes)
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.237   64-bit Windows: Yes
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.237   Processor architecture: x64
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.237   User privileges: Administrative
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.246   64-bit install mode: No
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:30.249   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-A1880.tmp
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.285   Starting the installation process.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.287   Creating directory: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.288   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Uninstaller
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.288   Creating directory: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Uninstaller
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.288   Creating new uninstall log: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Uninstaller\unins000.dat
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.290   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.290   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Uninstaller\unins000.exe
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.291   Time stamp of our file: 2018-02-13 14:46:30.175
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.291   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.294   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.295   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.296   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.296   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent.exe
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.296   Time stamp of our file: 2018-02-09 16:11:34.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.296   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.369   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.369   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.369   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.369   Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-18 09:37:06.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:53.370   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:55.579   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:55.579   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:55.580   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\CRRuntime_12_2_mlb.msi
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:55.580   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-15 14:57:46.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:55.580   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.603   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.604   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.604   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent.pdb
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.604   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-06 11:22:30.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.604   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.604   Creating directory: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.649   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.649   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.649   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\ImportExportGuide.txt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.650   Time stamp of our file: 2017-03-03 13:37:50.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.650   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.651   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.651   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.652   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Infragistics.Shared.v5.1.dll
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.652   Time stamp of our file: 2005-02-14 16:19:44.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.652   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.662   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.662   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.663   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.v5.1.dll
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.663   Time stamp of our file: 2005-02-15 12:13:28.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.663   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.717   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.717   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.718   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Infragistics.Win.v5.1.dll
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.718   Time stamp of our file: 2005-02-14 16:21:46.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.718   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.782   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.783   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.783   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\README.txt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.783   Time stamp of our file: 2018-02-05 15:04:58.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.783   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.785   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.785   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.785   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Databases\comm_db-TEST.mdb
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.785   Time stamp of our file: 2018-02-01 11:30:30.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.785   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:46:59.785   Creating directory: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Databases
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.028   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.029   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.029   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Databases\comm_db.mdb
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.029   Time stamp of our file: 2018-02-01 11:30:14.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.029   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.270   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.271   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.271   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BIACC.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.271   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-22 16:31:58.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.271   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.271   Creating directory: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.276   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.277   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.277   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BIACCAT.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.277   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-21 13:20:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.277   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.282   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.282   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.283   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BIACPC.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.283   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-21 13:20:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.283   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.287   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.288   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.288   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BIACPPC.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.288   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-22 16:32:16.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.288   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.293   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.293   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.293   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BIACT.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.293   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-22 16:31:40.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.293   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.297   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.297   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.298   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BIACTOT.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.298   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-22 16:31:06.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.298   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.302   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.302   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.302   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BICES.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.303   Time stamp of our file: 2017-03-13 12:45:22.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.303   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.307   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.307   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.308   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\BICF.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.308   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-22 09:58:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.308   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.312   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.312   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.312   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\CancelledNote.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.313   Time stamp of our file: 2017-07-26 13:41:46.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.313   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.319   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.320   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.320   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\CRDC.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.320   Time stamp of our file: 2017-03-01 10:17:30.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.320   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.326   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.326   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.326   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\CRDU.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.326   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-22 16:29:20.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.326   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.330   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.331   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.331   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\CRID.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.331   Time stamp of our file: 2018-01-26 14:04:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.331   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.357   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.357   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.358   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\CRISD.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.358   Time stamp of our file: 2017-06-09 11:01:32.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.358   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.362   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.362   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.362   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\CRISF.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.363   Time stamp of our file: 2018-01-26 14:04:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.363   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.377   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.377   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.377   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\CRVAT.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.378   Time stamp of our file: 2017-06-09 11:02:48.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.378   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.381   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.381   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.382   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\customerInfoReport.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.382   Time stamp of our file: 2017-07-18 16:16:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.382   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.386   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.386   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.387   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\DaysModificationsCondensed.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.387   Time stamp of our file: 2017-07-17 09:47:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.387   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.390   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.390   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.391   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\DaysModificationsLines.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.391   Time stamp of our file: 2017-08-01 10:45:10.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.391   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.395   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.395   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.395   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\MJGCustConf.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.395   Time stamp of our file: 2017-03-01 11:04:42.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.395   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.399   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.400   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.400   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\MJGOrderCancelledNotification.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.400   Time stamp of our file: 2017-03-01 11:06:38.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.400   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.404   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.404   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.404   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\MJGOrderCancelledOneAddress.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.405   Time stamp of our file: 2017-03-01 11:06:58.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.405   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.408   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.408   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.409   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\MJGRevisedNoteCust.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.409   Time stamp of our file: 2017-03-01 11:07:30.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.409   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.412   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.412   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.540   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\Iconysis Agent\Reports\VVQROP.rpt
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.540   Time stamp of our file: 2017-09-21 13:19:00.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.540   Installing the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.543   Successfully installed the file.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.544   -- File entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.544   Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.544   Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-18 09:37:06.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.544   Dest file exists.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.544   Time stamp of existing file: 2017-05-18 09:37:06.000
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.544   Version of our file: 12.0.4518.1014
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.637   Version of existing file: 12.0.4518.1014
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.637   Same version. Skipping.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.637   -- Icon entry --
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.638   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Iconysis Agent.lnk
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.638   Creating the icon.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.648   Successfully created the icon.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.698   Installation process succeeded.
>
> 2018-02-13 14:47:00.702   Need to restart Windows? No

Comment: 1) There's no code to execute `CRRuntime_12_2_mlb.msi` - So how does it relate to the question? 2) If you remove the `AfterInstall: RunAccessInstaller`, does the `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` get deleted?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, removing it doesn't change it, it's still there after install. RE your first point, it does still try to install CR runtimes, but an older version is already installed on my PC so it doesn't do it

Comment: So post [mcve]. Remove everything that is not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've asked you to remove everything that is not needed to reproduce the problem and you have added more code instead. - What if you focus on one of the subinstallers for now only, like the `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Apologies, I thought you meant you needed more of the script to see if the issue lied elsewhere, but for me to remove the parts of the script that weren't needed. Okay, focusing on the Access file only. It installs the runtime as expected and can be uninstalled separately from Control Panel, so no issue with that part, it just isn't deleting the file afterwards.

Comment: OK, but you wrote that you still get the problem even if you remove the `AfterInstall: RunAccessInstaller`, right? So I assume you can remove even that, including the `procedure RunAccessInstaller;`

Comment: Sure, but your question is not about installing Access database engine, but about removing the file after installation. So again, if you remove `RunAccessInstaller`, is the `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` removed after the installer finishes or not?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, it still doesn't delete the file.

Comment: OK, so update your question accordingly.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Okay, the question is updated. Is it possible it's skipping the flag perhaps? Alternatively, is there another way it can delete files?

Comment: Works for me. Note that the file is not deleted when the installation finishes, but only after you close the installer window.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That's what I've been checking. Even launching the app, closing it, then going back to the location it's installed in still shows that the file is there.

Comment: 1) Does Inno Setup log file show anything relevant? 2) What if you change an installation path?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I installed it to my desktop and it was the same, the files hadn't been deleted. Just trying to add in a setup log now, but when trying to set the location it's created in using `/LOG="C:\FileName.log" I get an "Unrecognized [Setup] section directive" error

Comment: `/LOG="C:\FileName.log` is a command-line switch, not a directive for .iss.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Okay, I created a log file and the only thing it says RE the Access file is that it's the same version so it skipped it

Comment: OK, so what if you delete it and then retry the installation?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've added the results into the post

Comment: You didn't remove the `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl because that file doesn't exist. To verify this, I've installed it again to admin\Documents and the log says the exact same thing. I think it may be referring to the directory, rather than the file itself

Comment: So when you do `dir "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe"` in `cmd.exe`, what does it say?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl "The system cannot find the specified file"

Comment: Post a complete Inno Setup log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Okay, done. I had to cut out about 20 .rpt files since there are absolutely loads, but the ones I missed out are all the same as the ones I've left in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two references to `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` in the log file.

```
2018-02-13 14:46:53.369 -- File entry --
2018-02-13 14:46:53.369 Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe
2018-02-13 14:46:53.369 Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-18 09:37:06.000
2018-02-13 14:46:53.370 Installing the file.
2018-02-13 14:46:55.579 Successfully installed the file.
```

```
2018-02-13 14:47:00.544 -- File entry --
2018-02-13 14:47:00.544 Dest filename: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Iconysis Agent\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe
2018-02-13 14:47:00.544 Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-18 09:37:06.000
2018-02-13 14:47:00.544 Dest file exists.
2018-02-13 14:47:00.544 Time stamp of existing file: 2017-05-18 09:37:06.000
2018-02-13 14:47:00.544 Version of our file: 12.0.4518.1014
2018-02-13 14:47:00.637 Version of existing file: 12.0.4518.1014
2018-02-13 14:47:00.637 Same version. Skipping.
```

That most probably means that you have two entries for `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` in the `[Files]` section.

I guess that you have one explicit entry for `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` and another wildcard entry what happens to match the same file. Something like:

```
[Files]
Source: "\\my_Directory\*"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "\\my_Directory\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: deleteafterinstall;
```

The first entry installs `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`. And it does not have the `deleteafterinstall` flag. The second entry does not install the file (as it's installed already), hence its `deleteafterinstall` has no effect.

Comment: Of course, I've just realised! It's with \*, the file itself is in that directory. I'll create a subfolder for the runtimes and see if that corrects it. Thanks for sticking with it :)